# How to calculate histogram using shared memory

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu-shared-memory

I want to calculate a histogram  using shared memory, and I write the code like below, but I found the result of CUDA and CPU is different, and the result of CUDA is `blockDim.x` times the result of the CPU, why?
And how can I fix it?
thank you!

```
__global__ void CalHistKernel(int*imgData,int*bins,int datasize)
{
    __shared__ int _bins[3];

    int tx=threadIdx.x;
    int idx=blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;//blockDim.y=1
    if(tx<3)
    {
        _bins[tx]=0;       
    }
    __syncthreads();

    if(idx<datasize)
    {       
        atomicAdd((int*)&_bins[imgData[idx]],1);     
    }
    __syncthreads();
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)   
        atomicAdd((int*)&bins[i],_bins[i]);
}
```

Comment: Irrelevant to your question but important: move your `__syncthreads();` out of conditional statement because your program may fail if all threads are not able to reach it.

Comment: yes,it is the problem.thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it's due due to the final loop, where you add the values in each shared memory bin to the global memory bins. Remember that the loop is executed in each thread.

Comment: thank you! I change the final loop,    atomicAdd((int*)&bins[tx],_bins[tx]); and then, it run correctly!

Comment: @user3226109: hi, can you edit the code to the correct ans? I want to learn from your example!